# What is the best audio and video recorder similar to Windows Media Encoder?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-streaming

I want to broadcast addressing of our leader and before we are on Windows and using *Windows Media Encoder* for this.

How can I get this functionality in Ubuntu 12.04?

Also I want save addressing in audio and video format, so please tell be best audio and video recorder options for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

recordmydesktop is buggy & inconsistant at best. Secondly, if I understand correctly, the op is not wanting to record a screencast, but external video. IF a screencast is what the op wants, ffmpeg is the most consistant & quality option. Heres a vid with instructions (for Arch, but same instruction in Ubuntu) http://youtu.be/BuKo0l3ZfEE

As for the best video editing/recording options? Kdenlive & Openshot for editing.
But the best way I found for recording webcam video is to open Kamerka (webcam app) in full screen while recording the screencast with ffmpeg as instructed in the video. I do this all the time & it works great.

Audio? Audacity is the clear winner here.

If you record the audio with the video, you can use kdenlive to extract the audio, then open that in audacity for any editing as the easiest way I know to get a seperate audio version that matches the video

Comment: Oh, and if you are talking about live streaming, check out http://Ustream.tv

Comment: @LinuxCplus i have server for live streaming but actually i want to ask we are using before Windows Media Encoder. Is there any alternative of Windows Media Encoder??

Comment: This is how to use FFMPEG :) http://www.wikihow.com/Record-Your-Desktop-Using-FFmpeg-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Answer (score 1):

You can install `gtk-recordMyDesktop` from software center. I think it will solve your problem.

RecordMyDesktop is one of the few video capture programs available in Ubuntu. Keeping with Linux’s free philosophy, RecordMyDesktop produces Ogg Theora video files out of your entire desktop, or just a selected section. If you haven’t heard of Ogg Theora, don’t worry – any modern video player will play these files, and you can even upload them to YouTube without having to convert them to another format.

Comment: Again, recordmydesktop is buggy & inconsistent. Video & audio are often misalligned or glitchy. ffmpeg does not have this problem.